# Dark hardwood floor stain

Tags: hardwood-floor, wood-finishing

More of a general question regarding floor staining.

We are removing the carpet to expose and use the hardwood floors. Floor boards are in good condition, and already have a finish. Some old paint splatter, which will be easy enough to remove. Plan is to fill in holes from nail punch and then restain.

All floor boards have a consistent colour. The one exception is the floorboards of the hallway, which seem to be a very dark colour. We will sand and finish, but my general question is, whether this stark contrast in finishing is something people have come across before.

[image: Hard-wood_floors]

Comment: “*general question is, whether this stark contrast in finishing is something people have come across before*”. This person has Not come across it before,  I can’t speak for other people. **Is there a DIY question here ?**

Comment: looks like the boards were effected by the black undercoat of the carpet

Comment: I'd give a patch a short soak in mineral spirits, flow by a scrub and wipe up. You might get lucky.

Comment: Not uncommon to have changes in color related to things like "this part was under a rug for 30 years and that part was not" and related sun exposure, lack of sun exposure, carpet pad gunk, wear/lack of wear, etc.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "have other people seen this" is not a Home Improvement question.

Answer (score 0):

Need more photos- but do you mean on the right? If so that looks to be more junk on top of your floor.

You may have to, depending on how bad they are, lever them out and flip them upside down. I had to rotate and flip about 30 boards in my house, and they came out just fine. I ended up getting some red oak stock as well to make the few I couldn't fix, but put them out of the way in corners.

Follow the guides for sanding and it should come up. However you may still have to flip them if they don't look right. Take for instance the nails- they've wrecked the wood around them and you won't bleach them out with Oxalate easily. Personally I wouldn't judge that harshly if I saw nails like that because I believe it adds character. And using oxalate is nasty.

Once everything was drum sanded down (be careful!), stained, and sealed, the place looked gorgeous.

-at least until a pipe burst and flooded everything in the middle of winter, gutting the place.

Answer (score 0):

> my general question is, whether this stark contrast in finishing is something people have come across before.

The last house I purchased and renovated had red oak hardwood in not one, not two, not three, but FOUR different stains throughout. The house is 1400 sq ft.

I later learned the prior three owners were artists of varying degree.

Comment: You've successfully answered the question, but this really doesn't add to the body of knowledge that would generally help people fix their own houses or even help the OP fix _his_ house. Knowing other people are in the same boat doesn't solve the problem. This type of answer is the only type of answer that's reasonable for the question and it's also the reason the question should have been closed in the first place.